# Prove or disprove : The limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z^3_n$ exists if and only if the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z_n$ exists

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, analytic-functions

Let $z_n$ be a complex sequence.
The limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z^3_n$ exists if and only if the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z_n$ exists

I think the statement is true. From the definition, an infinite sequence of complex numbers has a limit $z$ if, for each positive number $ε$, there exists a positive integer $n_0$ such that $|z_n − z|<ε$ whenever $n>n_0$.

How can I use the definition to prove the statement above? Is it true in the first place?

Comment: If $\zeta$ is a primitive third root of $1$ and $z_n= \zeta^{n \mod 3}$, then $z_n$ doesn't converge, but $z_n^3$ is constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is false. Let $\omega=-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i=e^{2\pi i/3}$, and let $z_n=\omega^n$. Then $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):z_n^{\,3}=1$, but the sequence $(z_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ diverges.

Comment: Can this counter example be used to disprove the opposite statement as well? ($\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z^3_n = inf$ if and only if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}z_n = inf$ )

Comment: What is $inf$? Do you mean $\infty$?

Comment: Yes I mean $\infty$

Comment: No. It is actually true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n^{\,3}=\infty\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=\infty$.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to think of the proof for this.

Comment: For complex numbers I would talk about $\lim_{n\to\infty} |z_n| = \infty$ rather than $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n=\infty$; the meaning of the latter expression can be ambiguous and depend upon the context.

Comment: Sorry do you mind guiding me through the proof?

Comment: I suggest that you post it as a new question.